# Optimizations When Installing to an SD Card

Tags: system-installation, ssd

Back in the day, there where a number of optimizations that were generally recommended [when installing Linux to an SD Card](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/09/04/four-tweaks-for-using-linux-with-solid-state-drives/):

- mount using the `noatime` option
- using a ramdisk for temp files
- put your browser cache in the ramdisk temp directory
- set the I/O scheduler to either `noop` or `deadline`
- run with no swap file ( my own addition )

Does Ubuntu, and most of it's derivates ( XUbuntu, LUbuntu,etc. ) do all these automatically when the installer sees that you're installing to an SD card?

I'm currently running XUbuntu 14.04.2 off an SD card, and when I installed I had to manually partition the card because the installer wanted to create a swap partition on the SD card.  However, after checking my I/O scheduler I see that it seems to be using `deadline`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you pretty much have to do most of the optimizations yourself.  But the biggest optimization is just to use the guest session, which basically sets up a temporary user in ram, so browser cache as well as all the hidden user files are takencare of.